# How to write a program to count the number of same elements and concatenate them into one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting large number of street names. I am trying count the number of each element in the dataframe and put them into a new dataframe. Then I wish to concatenate all the new dataframes into one single dataframe. But due to the large number of elements contained, I could only write a program that counts automatically.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
                                               Location
0                           BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH
1                           BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH
2                          LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
3                 VICTORIA EMBANKMENT J/W TEMPLE AVENUE
4                        HIGH HOLBORN J/W HATTON GARDEN
5            UPPER THAMES STREET J/W QUEEN STREET PLACE
6                        CANNON STREET J/W QUEEN STREET
7               QUEEN VICTORIA STREET J/W FRIDAY STREET
8                 KING WILLIAM STREET J/W ARTHUR STREET
9           LOWER THAMES STREET J/W LOWER THAMES STREET
10                     CORNHILL J/W KING WILLIAM STREET
11                     LONDON WALL J/W OLD BROAD STREET
12              QUEEN VICTORIA STREET J/W FRIDAY STREET
.
.
.
36735              MERIDIAN WAY J/W PICKETT'S LOCK LANE
36736                    WATERMEAD WAY J/W LEESIDE ROAD
36737                    WATERMEAD WAY J/W LEESIDE ROAD
36738                    WATERMEAD WAY J/W LEESIDE ROAD
```

I have the following code:

```
condition = (df[['Location']] == 'BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH').any(axis=1)
df2 = df[condition]

condition = (df[['Location']] == 'LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE').any(axis=1)
df3 = df[condition]
```

And so on for the rest of the elements in the dataframe, then I wish to concatenate all the dfs into one single dataframe

```
df_final = pd.concat([df2, df3, df4...dfn], axis=1)
```

So for example:

df2 =

```
                          Location
0      BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH
1      BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH
46     BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH
68     BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH
23108  BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH
```

df3 =

```
                           Location
2      LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
4481   LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
4515   LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
13705  LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
13744  LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
23172  LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
32341  LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
```

df_final =

```
df_final = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1)

                         Location                        Location
0     BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH    NaN 
1     BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH    NaN
2     NaN                            LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
46    BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH    NaN
68    BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH    NaN
4481  NaN                            LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
4515  NaN                            LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
13705 NaN                            LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
13744 NaN                            LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
23108 BISHOPSGATE J/W HOUNDSDITCH    NaN
23172 NaN                            LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
32341 NaN                            LONDON WALL J/W CIRCUS PLACE
```

Basically this concatenated dataframe will continue to increase in size until all elements have been counted.

As you can see due to the large number of elements(around 34000+), I will need to write a program that carry out the above process from the first to the last index. Are there any ways to approach this?

Comment: Do you want just the *numbers* for each unique street name, or do you want a reduced data frame with unique street names? I.e., a new dataframe with just numbers, or one with names?

Comment: Hi @Michael. Could you provide us with an example output and the input dataframe as text in the post itself rather than an image, so that it would allow us to  help you better?

Comment: There are the `unique` and `nunique` methods that work on a single column (Series); you probably want one of those.

Comment: `df.groupby('Location').size().reset_index()`.. ??